# Can i call a visualforce page on the click of a button in lightning and display an email template which has ids retrieved from a custom object?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, community, dynamic-visualforce

1. I have selected 3 out of say 10 and submitted it for updation in a lightning page(apex)( the fields in these 3 records need to be updated to new fields). 
   On the click of the **submit** button, we pass the list of ids of the records to be updated to an integration apex first.
2. In the integration apex, we first do "**SELECT * ..WHERE ID in**  " and retrieve all the values to be updated. we then call the SAP database and change the required fields in it and do the updation of the required fields.
3. After this we should go back to an apex class and save the required new fields back in our lightning page and get the ids of each record that we had to update. Then from the custom object, we need to get the **Owner ID** of each of these records so that we can finally generate **A VISUALFORCE PAGE** with a "custom" **email** **template** in which we display the record ids and owner ids of the list of records that were successfully updated and saved.

**IS IT POSSIble to do this? is it possible to **"dynamically"** get the ids and owner ids from the custom object and display it on a visualforce page from the lightning page all on the click of a** ***"submitbutton"***

Please reply **ASAP** and help me out here . Its needed **ASAP**. 
**Awaiting** your replies..

Comment: Your question is not properly explained. Please rephrase your question with details especially the 2nd part.

Comment: @SantanuHalder, I have rephrased it. Can you please help me out here??

Comment: Everything you mentioned seems doable but **we can finally generate A VISUALFORCE PAGE with a "custom" email template** this part seems confusing. Could you explain this?

Comment: @SantanuHalder, After the updation is done in the SAP, control comes back to the apex(lightning) class and we retrieve the owner IDS of the 3 records that had to be generated. and i want to know whether we can create a visualforce page with an email template **( Visualforce email template)** . This visualforce email template that displays some static content( graphics and company name and stuff) and displays the IDS of these updated records should be sent to the email ids of the ownerID ( which has to be extracted **DYNAMICALLY** .    *** IS THIS POSSIBLE? HOW IS ITPOSSIBLE??**

Answer (score 1):

So sending a list of Owners ID using a VF email template. Yes its possible.

You need to have a visualforce component first, say - OwnerIdDisplay

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="ComponentController">
    <apex:repeat value="{!ownerIds}" var="ownerId">
        {!ownerId}
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:component>
```

In your controller i.e ComponentController, have a static property which will hold all the owner ids.

```
    public static List<String> ownerIds{get;set;}
public static List<String> recordIds{get;set;}
```

Now, in your VF email template, with all other details(images & all) include the VF component.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="sample" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Account">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
<OwnerIdDisplay></OwnerIdDisplay>
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Next, after your SAP integration call when you have a list of owner ids, do this.

```
ComponentController.ownerIds = yourOwnerIdList; //assign the list to the static variable of the componentcontroller class which is the controller for VF component.

ComponentController.recordIds = yourRecordIdList; //assign the list to the static variable of the componentcontroller class which is the controller for VF component.
```

Next, *after the above code,* fire the email using the email template.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = 
            new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

   mail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId()); // to whomsoever you want to send the email to
   mail.setTemplateId('00X900000022nfB');

   mail.setBccSender(false);
   mail.setUseSignature(false);
   mail.setReplyTo('recruiting@acme.com');
   mail.setSenderDisplayName('HR Recruiting');
   mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);  

Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try it out and get back to you! Hope you will be available if i have any more doubts and queries.  Thanks a ton again Santz!

Comment: So sending a list of Owners ID using a VF email template. Yes its possible.

You need to have a visualforce component first, say - OwnerIdDisplay

<apex:component access="global" controller="ComponentController">
    <apex:repeat value="{!ownerIds}" var="ownerId">
        {!ownerId}
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:component> ,, **You meant , create a lightning component right???**

Comment: ** In my email template, i need to show the recordID of those records that could be updated and saved. And these record IDS need to be fetched DYNAMICALLY each time. IS THIS POSSIBLE????????**

Comment: No, I meant visualforce component. And yes, you need to have another public static list of string in the ComponentController which will hold the record ids. Pass the record ids to that like I did for owner ids after the SAP integration.

Comment: can you please attach the code for the same?

Comment: 'Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = 
            new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

   mail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId()); // to whomsoever you want to send the email to
   mail.setTemplateId('00X900000022nfB');

   mail.setBccSender(false);
   mail.setUseSignature(false);
   mail.setReplyTo('recruiting@acme.com');
   mail.setSenderDisplayName('HR Recruiting');
   mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);  

Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });' - **where shuld i be attaching this?** Also the submit button is on a lightning component. @SantanuHalder

Comment: The above code will fire an email. You should add it after the SAP integration code. See my updated answer.